# Calculations of double integral of $xy^2$ over the region between $y=0$ and $y=4-x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find $\iint_D f~\mathrm{d}A $ where $f(x,y) = xy^2$. Region 
>   $D$ is between $y=0$ and $y=4-x^2$

If you draw the graph, you can see that it equal to $0$, however if you calculate the answer (acording to my friend) is $32/3$.

So what is the answer and how do you solve this correctly?

Help please. Thanks.

Comment: You need to determine bounds on $D$. The question gives you bounds for $y$ and you need to solve $0=4-x^2$ to find your $x$ bounds. Then you can integrate it (in the correct order!)

Comment: Can you show me please? I'd like if you do.

Comment: Disregard my earlier answer.

Comment: Your friend integrated the function $4-x^2$ over $[-2,2]$ which is where the ${ 32 \over 3}$ came from.

Comment: @copper.hat - I don't get it... you did it too but we get $0$

Comment: The correct answer is zero, I am just guessing at the mistake your friend made, since I did the same :-).

Comment: @copper.hat - could you show me also the mistake? just so I could know why it's not true.

Comment: I believe your friend computed the area $D$, not the integral of $f$ over the $D$. Specifically, $\int_{-2}^2 (4-x^2) dx = { 32 \over 3}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral should be $0$ since the domain symmetric about the $y$-axis and $xy^{2}$ is odd in $x$. Alternatively you can calculate it:

$$
\int\int_{D}xy^{2}dA = \int_{-2}^{2}\int_{0}^{4-x^{2}}xy^{2}dydx=\int_{-2}^{2}x\frac{(4-x^{2})^{3}}{3}dx=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

The region of integration $D$ can be seen here:

[image]

You can mechanically evaluate $\int_{x=-2}^2 \int_{y=0}^{4-x^2} xy^2 dydx = 0$.

We can write $D=D_- \cup D_0 \cup D_+$, where $D_- = \{ (x,y) \in D | x<0 \}$ and similarly for the others. Then note that the integral over $D_0$ is zero, and $(x,y) \in D_+$ **iff** $(-x,y) \in D_-$, and since $f(-x,y) = -f(x,y)$, we have $\int_{D_+} f = - \int_{D_-} f$, from which we see that $\int_D f = 0$.

Comment: Nice answer and picture. (+1) (from a while ago)